# Authentification fail in bad request : Missing Credentials

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm working on a Passport Node.js, Express login page.
I'm a Web Developer but this is my first Node.js project.

I have followed [User Authentication with Passport.js](https://mherman.org/blog/user-authentication-with-passport-dot-js/)

But every time I try to log in the login page, or the Register page, the only thing I have is a "Bad request" page.

I made a call back to see what happened:

```
exports.postRegister = function(req, res) {
    login = mongoose.model('login');
    login.register(new login({
        username: req.body.email
    }), req.body.password, function(err, login) {
        if (err) {
            return res.render('register', {
                login: login,
                error: err,
                title: "S'enregistrer"
            });
        }
        // Something is wrong here 
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
            // So let's console log the thing !
            console.log(arguments);
        })(req, res, function() {
            res.redirect('/scene/1');
        });
    });
};
```

And the `console.log (arguments)` return:

```
{
  '0': null,
  '1': false,
  '2': { message: 'Missing credentials' },
  '3': 400
}
```

I have check on my MongoDB, the user is created without problems!

Comment: Exactly the same thing just hapened to me... same tuto. Did you find your way through ?

Comment: Yes, I just remove the passport mongoose plugin and do all the implementation by hand :P

Comment: I found this http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local. And it's working great so far

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not specifying a schema for your `login` model. You need to declare models like this:

`var Model = mongoose.model('Model', 'modelSchema');`

Comment: I know, it is because I used the passport plugin to mongo (Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);) that didn't work in this tutorial which is official !!
http://mherman.org/blog/2013/11/11/user-authentication-with-passport-dot-js/#.U-Ov1_l5N8E

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see whether it comes from POSTMAN or your code, you can test with curl in a terminal:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "test", "password": "test"}' http://localhost:3000/api/login
```

Comment: The probleme was the Mongoose plugin ! I juste removed it, code the login by hand  and it work like a charm  :P